# Ability to count repeated row IDs in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I am trying to count all repeated IDs within a MySQL table.

Here is the table which I generate after running this query

```
   SELECT
      aid, uid, timestamp
    FROM
      login_activity
    where uid <> 0
    order by uid


aid | uid | timestamp
----------------------- 
17  |  43  | 1507677429
63  |  73  | 1507677429
101 |  91  | 1507677429
45  |  109 | 1507677429
1   |  423 | 1507677429
3   |  423 | 1507677429    
23  |  431 | 1507677429
19  |  431 | 1507677429
8   |  431 | 1507677429
7   |  445 | 1507677429
6   |  445 | 1507677429
33  |  445 | 1507677429
9   |  445 | 1507677429
```

Here I want to get `3` as there are three instances where uid is repeated. These are `423`, `431`and `445`. We will discard `43, 73, 91, 109` as they are not repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  I would recommend starting with two aggregations:

```
select count(*)
from (select uid
      from login_activity
      where uid <> 0
      group by uid
      having count(*) > 1
     ) la;
```

An alternative with only one aggregation uses filtering (and assumes that `aid`/`uid` is unique):

```
select count(distinct la.uid)
from login_activity la
where exists (select 1
              from login_activity la2
              where la2.uid = la.uid and la2.aid <> la.aid
             );
```